# How to generate a ClientContext from SiteId in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SiteId and I want to generate a `ClientContext` to fetch all the groups of that particular site. But I am not able to find a way to generate a ClientContext from the SiteId same we do in SharePoint on-premises.

Is there a way to generate a ClientContext from SiteId in SharePoint Online or we need the URL only?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
using(var context = new ClientContext(new GUId(siteId))
{
//TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your `ClientContext` in two steps:

- search the site by its ID using the search API
- create a client context using the site's URL

Here's some PowerShell doing exactly this. I'm using the [PnP Cmdlets](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) out of convenience, similar results can also be achieved using plain CSOM.

```powershell
# this is your site's ID
$siteId = "a20d2341-1b4f-47ed-8180-24a5c31adfa9"
# basically any known site URL - the root is probably fine
$anySiteUrl = "https://<yourtenant>.sharepoint.com"
$credential = Get-Credential

Connect-PnPOnline –Url $anySiteUrl –Credentials $credential
# search for site by ID
$site = Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "SiteID:$siteId AND ContentClass=STS_Site"
if ($site.ResultRows.Count -eq 1) 
{
    # URL to use for "real" connection
    $siteUrl = $site.ResultRows[0].Path
    Connect-PnPOnline –Url $siteUrl –Credentials $credential
    $currentSite = Get-PnPSite
    # and there is your ClientContext
    $ctx = Get-PnPContext
    $web = $currentSite.RootWeb
    $ctx.Load($web)
    $ctx.Load($web.SiteGroups)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    # here are your groups
    $web.SiteGroups
}
```

(Note: you *must* install the [SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) PowerShell module for this code to run.)